# How does make know what needs to be compiled?

Tags: makefile

Make is a very handy and capable feature for developing and more specifically compiling software.  What process does it actually use to determine which files get recompiled when necessary (touched files) vs skipping over files which have not been touched?

Answer (score 4):

It checks the modification dates of prerequisites and compares them to the modification dates of targets.  If any prerequisites is newer, that target is rebuilt.

There are some special cases (phony targets, for example), but that's pretty much all there is to it.